# Converting datastream InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] to a Twitter object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to build a spark application which will pull Twitter data from Kafka and then do a processing  and finally store the complete output .Below is my spark scala code

```
package sparkWCExample.spWCExample

import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext,SparkSession}


import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
import kafka.serializer.Decoder
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder

import com.stanford_nlp.SentimentAnalyzer.SentimentAnalyzer
import sparkWCExample.spWCExample.ExternalClass.SentimentAnalyzerDetails

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import scala.collection.Seq

object twitterSentiment  {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
 /* if (args.length < 4) {
  System.err.println("Usage: TwitterPopularTags <consumer key> <consumer secret> " + "<access token> <access token secret> [<filters>]")
  System.exit(1)
  }*/
  //val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("twitter-stream-sentiment").setMaster("local[2]")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext

 sc.setLogLevel("WARN") 
 val sentiment_analyzer = new SentimentAnalyzerDetails
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5)) 

        val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("bigdata-tweets")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( ssc,  PreferConsistent,  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

val streamdata = stream.map(record => println("record data "+record.key+ " "  +record.value))
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreach{x=> println("record -->"  +x.value())
    }
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

   }
```

now when I am doing the `rdd.foreach` and printing the value of x.value , I am getting the below data

Tweet{id=1242897366950297602, text='RT @MattRiMo: #COVIDー19 320 000 téléconsultations facturées à l’Assurance maladie depuis le 15 septembre 2018, dont 115 000 depuis le 1er m…', lang='fr', user=User{id=4241334975, name='FEIMA', screenName='FeimaEditeurs', location='null', followersCount=1010}, retweetCount=0, favoriteCount=0}
Tweet{id=1242897367231315975, text='RT @MarceVann: Il 22 febbraio la #RegioneLombardia rispondeva così alla urgente segnalazione da parte di un dirigente sanitario di Bergamo,…', lang='it', user=User{id=1233696142032015360, name='Luigi Salerno', screenName='LuigiSa45451613', location='null', followersCount=84}, retweetCount=0, favoriteCount=0}

After than I am getting confused how I can convert the data into a dataframe or dataset or to map to a class, so that I can fetch the text from Tweet data and do something on it .
Please help